# react-router@3.0.2, Error: Cannot find module 'history/lib/createLocation'

Tags: reactjs, react-router

what's going on with `react-router@3.0.2`?

below is my code:

`import createLocation from 'history/lib/createLocation';`

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: @SunnyRGupta Yes.But I do not think is my `webpack` config problem.

Comment: I found some other people were having issues with the same stuff. It is generally due to improper linkage of dependencies.

Comment: I pretty sure is `react-router` version problem. But I do not know what's going on.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/2970
People have encountered this issue along with react-router version 1.0.3 as well. I'm sure it's not a problem with `react-router`.

Answer (score 0):

Update npm - `npm install npm@latest -g`

Please run `npm install` or `yarn install` to make sure all dependencies are downloaded and linked.

Comment: I do not think is my `dependencies` problem. `npm` v3, all `dependencies` and `devDependencies` were installed.

Comment: Might have to reinstall. After an update. Have faced such issues in past. Simply delete your node_modules folder. Suggest to upgrade to latest version of npm as well.